# Multi-level Models - Date as a Random Effect

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

Hi I was wondering if someone would be able to help me decide on the proper set up for a multi-level model using the lmer package.

In my study, we are looking at heart rate in beats per minute before and after a medication. Some of the participants have a different number of observations, but each observations is identified with a day and month. And there is no day and month that overlaps among any of the patients.

For instance:

```
    id BPM  Day    Drug
    1  80   3/10   No
    1  49   3/10   Yes
    1  50   4/11   No
    1  87   4/11   Yes
    2  47   4/12   No
    2  47   4/12   Yes
    3  43   5/1    No
    3  45   5/1    Yes
```

In setting up the model, to control for the fact, that these are paired, could one concivably write it as either (I believe these set ups would give same results):

```
    lmer(BPM ~ Drug + (1 + Drug | id/Date))
                     or
    lmer(BPM ~ Drug + (1 + Drug | id) + (1 | Date))
```

Is it okay to treat Date as a random effect? We aren't interested in time as an effect, just using it as a categorical variable to identify that these are paired? Would this be the best/appropriate approach?

Comment: The approach seems reasonable. I believe the setups you have are somewhat different because drug doesn't vary by date in the second one. So the first setup may be preferable because you can see if dates with drug yes vary more than dates with drug no.

Comment: Yeah I actually think we wouldnt want to assume that the effect of drug varies by date. The dates themselves are not really important. They just classify the day the test took place but we are not looking at the effect of time and don't believe it should influence (even if likely does, but that's out of our scope right now). 

Thank you so very much for your answer. Someone else from a different post, spoke about the potential of collinearity? Are you able to speak to that as a potential problem that may arise from this set up?

Comment: The potential of collinearity of?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/92ra2n/multilevel_model_random_effects_date/ 

The user here thinks that using date as a random effect could possibly cause problems with "flirting with collinearity and numerical problems".

Edit: I wasn't sure if collinearity is between random effects? If so, then I think this would be a problem with ID as well. Unless the user means collinearity between ID and Date?

Comment: I think it is worth trying. If you have enough people and enough dates, it should not be a problem. lme4 is usually over the top with warnings, so I would take a run it and see approach.

Comment: What did you end up deciding with this? I'm in a similar situation with traditional clinical statisticians telling me i cant use date as a random effect, but for me, day just represents the calendar day the measurement was taken, not anchored in a diagnosis or intervention or anything. TO me it cant be anything but random, but i'm having a hard time articulating that!

Comment: Hi @JenRooney Rooney, I did not end up using date as a random effect as I was never clear whether it was okay, and thinking back, in my case I don't think it was. I'm not an expert in statistics, but is the idea that for a specific subject, you may have multiple measurements on the same day and also multiple measurements on different days?